# UITableViewCell scroll detecting

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have pangesture recognizer in custom `UITableViewCell` and I want to disable it during table view scrolling. Is it possible to detect in custom `UITableViewCell` is table view is scrolling?

Comment: as UITableview inherits for scrollview you can use scrollview delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll ` when scroll is happened.

Comment: How can I send this information in table view cell?

Answer (score 1):

As @jarvis12 mentioned in comment, `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView` and you can take advantage of its delegate methods.

1. Add a global bool variable which will act as a flag to check current state of scrolling.

   ```
   var isScrolling = false
   ```
2. Add two `UIScrollView` delegate methods and update `isScrolling` variable as below:

   ```
   func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       self.isScrolling = true
   }

   func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
       self.isScrolling = false
   }
   ```
3. In your `UITableViewCell` simply add following if condition:

   ```
   if isScrolling {
       //disable pan gesture
   }
   else {
       //enable pan gesture
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have `CustomTableViewCell` which inherits `UITableViewCell`. `isScrolling` is in `ViewController` and pan gesture is in custom cell, how to get this information from VC?

Comment: Would you mind adding code in your question which show where you are adding gestures?

Answer (score 1):

Use this extension for detect specific tableview scrolling in iOS Swift

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == tableName {
            // write logic for tableview disble scrolling
        }
    }
}
```